# How to remember previous URL after redirecting with document.location.replace

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

So I'm experimenting with bookmarklets where I want to go to a certain location by clicking on a bookmarklet. Please see the code to understand better.

```
javascript:currentUrl=document.location.href;document.location.replace(currentUrl+'/images')
```

By using this bookmarklet when on
`google.com`,
you will be redirected to 
`Google Images`.
 But why is it that it does not remember the previous link,
`google.com`?
 The back button on the browser is also grayed out... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name of the method suggests, `replace()` will replace/overwrite the URL and will not save to the user's browsing history. According to [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace):

> The `Location.replace()` method replaces the current resource with the one at the provided URL. The difference from the `assign()` method is that after using `replace()` the current page will not be saved in session History, meaning the user won't be able to use the back button to navigate to it.

If you want to write to the session history, you can either do:

- [`window.location.assign(url)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign), or
- [`window.location.href = url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Comment: Thanks, 
`assign`
was what i wanted. Will accept your answer in 4 minutes